# How to embed a asm code block into c program which is compiled with clang and will be run on Android

Tags: android, c, assembly, clang

As know, we can embed asm code into C program, such as below.

```
void make_dir() {
int ret = 0;
char *dir = "./test_asm";
int mode = 0777;
asm volatile(
        "movl $39, %%eax\n\t"
        "int $0x80\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %0\n\t"
        : "=m"(ret)
        : "b"(dir), "c"(mode));
}
```

But there will be build error when I compile it on android with clang in Android Studio. The error message is such as "Error:(96, 7) error: invalid input constraint 'b' in asm".

Why does this happen?

Comment: If your android is running some kind of arm processor you will not be able to use x86 assemly and related constraints.

Comment: Don't do this. There is literally no reason you need to for an application running on Android.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes, it is arm processor. Do you know how to embed asm into c program on android?

Comment: Your problem isn't that embedding asm into a c program isn't working.  The problem is that the asm you are trying to embed is "x86 asm" and you need "arm asm" if you are going to be running on arm.  But more importantly is what @R.. is saying: There is no reason to use asm at all if all you are doing is creating a directory.  Just write it in C.  Lack of portability to other platforms is one of the many reasons [not to use asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).

Answer (score 2):

The code you're trying to assemble is not a good way to make a directory. It is specific to 32-bit x86 processors, and can't assemble for, or run on, the ARM processors that are in almost all Android devices. It's buggy because it fails to declare that it clobbers the EAX register, and it's silly to use a memory output operand and write your own mov store instead of just telling the compiler where it can find the result (in EAX with "=a"(ret)).

If this assembler code fragment is the only way you know to create a directory in C, than you need to learn the normal C way of doing it. That will work fine on reasonably modern versions of Android (at least 5.0 onwards, I've never looked at anything older), whatever processor they are running, and also on just about any UNIX-derived operating system. It is easier to read and maintain, and has no significant speed penalty. Here's a simple example:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

void make_dir() {
char *dir = "./test_asm";
int mode = 0777;
    if (0 != mkdir( dir, mode)) {
        printf( "Directory creation failed\n");
    }
}
```

The mkdir call, and its returned value, is explained in more detail in just about any book on C, and in the documentation of any decent set of developer tools.

Comment: The OP's inline asm makes sense; it uses `"b"(dir), "c"(mode)` input constraints to ask for `dir` in EBX and `mode` in ECX, the first 2 `int 0x80` arg-passing registers.  It's buggy because it fails to declare a clobber on EAX, and it's stupid to use a memory output operand and write your own `mov` store instead of just telling the compiler where it can find the result (in EAX with `"=a"(ret)`).  Using inline asm at all doesn't make sense, though, and using a slow `int 0x80` is also silly even if targeting only 32-bit x86, vs. calling through the VDSO to allow `sysenter` instead.